# Swift animation after dismissing UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, animation, uistackview

I try to add an image to a stackview with an animation after the UIImagePickerController is dissmissed. But the animation doesn't work at all. How can I make sure, that the animation takes place after the controller is dismissed? 
It seems that the animation is hindered by die dismiss animation of the UIImagePickerController.

The ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class CustomViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var customView: CustomView!
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customView = CustomView.init(profilePic: UIImage(named: "profilePic")!)
        customView.addPictureSegment.addPictureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onAddPicture), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(customView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //Open imagePicker to take picture
    @objc func onAddPicture() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
        customView.addPictureSegment.addImage(image: image)
    }
}
```

Custom View:

```
class CustomeView: UIScrollView {

    var contentView: UIView!
    var addPictureSegment: HorizontalPictureGallery!

    init(profilePic: UIImage) {
        super.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
        self.contentView = UIView()
        self.addSubview(self.contentView)
        self.setupPicSegment()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupPicSegment() {
        //Add picture segment
        addPictureSegment = HorizontalPictureGallery()
        contentView.addSubview(addPictureSegment)
    }
}
```

The View carries the stackview:

```
class HorizontalPictureGallery: UIScrollView {

    var addPictureButton: AddImageButton!
    var contentView: UIView!
    var horizontalImageStackView: UIStackView!

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        contentView = UIView()
        addPictureButton = AddImageButton()

        self.addSubview(contentView)

        setupStackView()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupStackView() {
        horizontalImageStackView = UIStackView()
        horizontalImageStackView.axis = .horizontal
        horizontalImageStackView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        horizontalImageStackView.spacing = MyMargins.mediumMargin

        horizontalImageStackView.addArrangedSubview(addPictureButton)
        self.addSubview(horizontalImageStackView)
    }

    @objc func addImage(image: UIImage) {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        imageView.isHidden = true
        horizontalImageStackView.insertArrangedSubview(imageView, at: 0)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: horizontalImageStackView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.9){
            imageView.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Animating `.isHidden` doesn't work with `UIView.animate`. If you use the `animate` method, you have to have `.isHidden` false and change `alpha` from 0 to 1. Instead, try a transition:

```
UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.9, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        imageView.isHidden = false
    })
```

Comment: That didn't work. I set with:horizontalImageStackView since this is the container of the imageView which should be animated. That still does not show any animation.

Comment: Its a step in the right direction, as you need to transition unless you are animating alpha. Have you set a breakpoint in the debugger to make sure it is being called on the main thread?

Comment: It's running on the same thread as the dismiss of the UIImapgePickerController. Is this supposed to be like that?

Comment: I would expect them to be on the main thread, which should be called something like "Thread 1". Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's the case. Also I tested the animation with .isHidden standalone and it worked (like here: https://medium.com/@nrewik/easy-animation-with-uistackview-8878b2856ae2). But in combination with the imagePicker.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil) it doesn't work.

Comment: I've had animation issues coming back from in-app purchases because while some apple interfaces are presented, your app is technically backgrounded. Maybe it is with this too? The way I got around that was to leave a flag, detect the app foregrounding, and run the animation if there is a flag.